# Error b'' trying to install psycopg2 on AIX 7.2

Tags: python, psycopg2, aix

I am trying to install psycopg2==2.9.6 on AIX 7.2.  The first thing I did was install postgresql 13.10 from source in order to get pg_config.

Now when I try to run `setup.py build` I get this blank error message:

```
python -v setup.py build
...
running build_ext
# /opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/__pycache__/_sysconfigdata_m_aix7_.cpython-37.pyc matches /opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/_sysconfigdata_m_aix7_.py
# code object from '/opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/__pycache__/_sysconfigdata_m_aix7_.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_sysconfigdata_m_aix7_' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0xa000000008b7f08>
Error: b''
```

I get the same error when trying to install directly with pip.  My pip, setuptools and wheel packages are all up to date.  I'm not sure where to go from here, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the OS build tools installed?

Comment: Try `python3 setup.py` too.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I think that it is already pointing at Python 3.7: `/home/nolan/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py`

Comment: What are the package versions for pip, setuptools and wheel in your `env`? I just ran `python setup.py -v build_ext --pg-config /usr/local/pgsql14/bin/pg_config build` in a Python 3.7 env on my machine and it was successful. This was with `setuptools           41.2.0`. The reason I ask is in my site-packages I do not see `...config/setupcfg.py`. There is no `config/` just a  `config.py`.

Comment: I'm using pip-23.1 and setuptools-67.6.1.  I also tried with 41.2.0, same error.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of at the moment is to file an issue here [Psycopg2 issues](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIX is not officially supported:

https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1561